# How/where to create GNOME custom keybinding override file?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, gnome3, fedora-24

I've been trying to use [puppet-gnome](https://github.com/camptocamp/puppet-gnome) to create custom keyboard shortcuts, with no luck. I've got the following schema:

```
class keyboard_shortcuts {
  $schema_root = 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys'
  $custom_keybinding_schema = "${schema_root}.custom-keybinding"
  $first_key = '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/'
  $first_schema = "${custom_keybinding_schema}:${first_key}"

  gnome::gsettings { $schema_root:
    schema => $schema_root,
    key    => 'custom-keybindings',
    value  => [
      "'${first_key}'"
    ],
  }

  gnome::gsettings { "${custom_keybinding_schema}_name":
    schema => $first_schema,
    key    => 'name',
    value  => 'Terminal',
  }

  gnome::gsettings { "${custom_keybinding_schema}_command":
    schema => $first_schema,
    key    => 'command',
    value  => '/usr/bin/terminator',
  }

  gnome::gsettings { "${custom_keybinding_schema}_binding":
    schema => $first_schema,
    key    => 'binding',
    value  => '<Ctrl><Alt>T',
  }
}
```

This creates the following files:

```
$ ls /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/25_*
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/25_org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding_binding.gschema.override  /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/25_org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.gschema.override
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/25_org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding_command.gschema.override  '/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/25_Raise window on click.gschema.override'
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/25_org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding_name.gschema.override
$ sudo cat /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/25_*
[org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/]
  binding = <Ctrl><Alt>T
[org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/]
  command = /usr/bin/terminator
[org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/]
  name = Terminal
[org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys]
  custom-keybindings = ['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/']
[org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences]
  raise-on-click = true
```

However, in the "Keyboard" applet I don't see this keyboard shortcut. If I create a keyboard shortcut manually and apply the manifest it doesn't even get rid of the existing shortcut. Do I need to create the overrides elsewhere? I've tried `/usr/share/GConf/gsettings` because that seems like a more natural place for such files, but no go.

---

I also tried using a `digest` of the shortcut name instead of `custom0`. The schema compiled successfully, but still no go:

```
$ strings /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled | grep custom-keybindings/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/514d8a494f087c0d549b9536c2ef3bd9/
```

---

[Related question](https://ask.puppet.com/question/27731/how-to-apply-gnome-settings-to-current-session/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should use `gsettings`. Check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/597414) for details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).